Solve the system $\begin{cases} 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)=1\\ x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2=xyz(x+y+z)^3 \end{cases}$
I have to solve the system \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      3(x^2+y^2+z^2)=1\\
      x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2=xyz(x+y+z)^3
    \end{cases}\
\end{equation}
Where $x,y,z$ are real numbers. I am stuck thinking how to use thee Newton's identities to relate all the polynomials given that all of them are symmetric. Could you give me a little hint?

Sal's conjecture suggests: How about doing this as a Lagrange multiplier problem?  Minimize $x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to $x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2=xyz(x+y+z)^3$.  If the mimimum is $1/3$, then the points where that is achieved are your solutions.

@SaiMehta No, this is obviously not true. Take $x=y=0$ and $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Hint: Show that under the first condition, $x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 +z^2x^2 \geq xyz(x+y+z)^3$. Equality holds when $xy=yz=zx$.

Have you tried spherical coordinates.

$x,y,z=- \frac{1}{3}$ works too

@hamam_Abdallah I have tried but the second equality is giving me a rough time

Hints towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried and why you can't push through.

First inequality: Show that for reals $x, y, z$, we have $ 3(x^2+y^2+z^2) \geq (x+y+z)^2 \geq 0$

Equality holds iff $ x=y=z$.


Second inequality: Show that for reals $x, y, z$, we have  $x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2 \geq xyz (x+y+z)$. Equality holds when $xy=yz=zx$.


Proof hint: Look at the equality condition and find a Sum of Squares that is hopefully obvious.

 $$x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2 - xyz (x+y+z) = \frac{(xy-yz)^2 + (yz-zx)^2 + (zx-xy)^2}{2}.$$


Show that the equality condition in the second inequality implies that we only have the following cases:

All 3 equal.
2 of them are equal, and both are 0.


Third inequality: Given that $3(x^2+y^2+z^2) = 1$, show that
$$ \begin{align} & x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2 \\
= \, & 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\times (x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2) \\
\geq \, & (x+y+z)^2 \times xyz(x+y+z) \\
= \,  & xyz(x+y+z)^3 \end{align} $$

Be careful with multiplying inequalities where values need not be negative.


Show that equality in the third inequality implies that we only have the following cases:

Equality in the first inequality and equality in the second inequality.
Both sides in the second inequality are 0.


Hence, conclude that the only solutions are

$\pm ( \frac{1}{3} , \frac{1}{3} ,  \frac{1}{3} ) $
Cyclic permutations of $(0, 0, \pm  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} )$




I was trying the hint of spherical coordinates but had a rough time on the second equality. I am going to try this hint now, thanks!

With your comment and the above from @orangeskid I got the problem, thanks!

@MiguelCG The SOS (Sum of squares) is almost obvious, so I'd recommend you think about it that way. Of course, if you're just wanting to be spoon-fed the solution, then you are done.

Sorry if I can not catch those SOS you are talking about, I am not used to this kind of olympiad problems. I will continue thinking about it.

By the way, the inequality right hand side should be powered to 3, not to 2.

Edited and added details.

Do you have any tip for someone like me that do not see that often those relationship? Maybe a book?

Heads up that I missed the cube power when writing up the solution. That explains why my comment hint was "show that under the first condition, ..." whereas I didn't reflect that here. I've edited this in now. $\quad$ As for the tip,   Do not see it as "I could not have solved this problem without knowing that identity. So I need to find a book that lists out all possible relationships and memorize them" (which is how I'm interpreting your ask).

Hint: Show that
$$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2) - x y z(x+y+z)^3 \ge 0$$
for $x$, $y$, $z$ positive numbers ( a homogenous symmetric inequality), and so for all real numbers, and check the equality case.
$\bf{Added:}$  Let's check the above inequality first for positive numbers. Being symmetric, we may assume $0\le x \le y \le z$. So write $x=u$, $y=u+v$, $z=u+v+w$, expand, and see that all of the appearing monomials in $u$, $v$, $w$ have positive coefficients.
For arbitrary numbers, check that LHS is the same if $x$ is substituted by $|x|$ and so on, while the RHS increases.
We get equality if and only if  $x=y=z$ or two of them are $0$.

Can I ask if there is any resource that I can check about these homogenous symmetric inequalyties? I feel like I am missing something

the method proposed is mechanic (also known as the Buffalo Way), perhaps there are other nicer ones.

Thanks! I do not know if there are other method of reaching the solution but this is really nice.
